# how to apply a relative position to an iFrame

Tags: html, css

```
<iframe width="1280" height="720" scr="https://https://www.youtube.com/embed/_lE1GYParQA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
```

```
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#showcase {
  margin-top: 5px;
  min-height: 450px;
  text-align: center;
  background: url('../Pictures/Showcase.png') no-repeat 0 -280px;
  color: #000;
  border: 2px;
}

#Video {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  max-width: 1280px;
  max-height: 720px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  /* 16x9 aspect ratio */
  border: 2px blue solid;
}

#video iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7xt8mccu/
ive got a relative iframe which goes by 16x9 by the image of the youtube video doesn't resize, is there a way to resize that img when the screen get smaller?
thank you in advanced

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I voted to close as a Typographical error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works. You just made a case mistake.

In your CSS, replace

```
#video iframe {
```

with

```
#Video iframe {
```

(capital V) and it works. See https://jsfiddle.net/ns1mrfy5/